# How to concat data into one object in JS?

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to add new values to object in Javascript/Typescript?

I have this JSON:

```
{
   "firstname":"chris",
   "lastname":"bosh"
}
```

and this one:

```
{
   "login":"c.bosh",
   "email: "c.bosh@bosh.com"
}
```

how to concat this two object into one, like this:

```
{
   "firstname":"chris",
   "lastname":"bosh",
   "login":"c.bosh",
   "email: "c.bosh@bosh.com"
}
```

Comment: `const result = { ...firstPart, ...secondPart };`

Comment: If you want to keep the reference to one of them use `Object.assign(first, second)`